# Kubernetes : How can I get access to a previously killed (and not restarted) pod?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, aerokube-moon

I have a deployment on my Kubernetes on Azure (AKS), and pods related to that deployment get killed. Is there any simple way to see logs of the killed pod ?

PS:
This deployment is `aerokube moon2`, which **creates** other pods corresponding to tests and **deletes** them based on web-socket connection. For some reason, one of the moon2 replicas gets killed and the created pod by moon2 still running.

Comment: Did you try the `kubectl logs <pod> —previous`

Comment: it works only with restarted pods and not killed